# Can not connect to Google+ with new API

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus

I can't connect to Google+ using [start integrating Google+ into your Android app](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started) .

Its very simple, but with new com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.3.0 class PlusClient and PlusClient.Bulder can not resolve. I need to get user information like: url of avatar and First/Last name by email.

Can you help me?

P.S: when I add to gradle dependensies com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71 class PlusClient can resolved, but I exceed the limit of methods. And when I add only play-services-plus, it not work

Comment: which version of google play services you are using now.

Comment: I'm using 7.3.0 version

Comment: can you tell me revision number.

Comment: sorry, but where I can check it?

Answer (score 0):

PlusClient.Bulder is removed from revision number 23 and right now google play services revision num is 24.

you can able to access the google plus login by using

```
     private GoogleApiClient buildGoogleApiClient() {
    // When we build the GoogleApiClient we specify where connected and
    // connection failed callbacks should be returned, which Google APIs our
    // app uses and which OAuth 2.0 scopes our app requests.
    return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(SigninActivity.this).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
  }
```

call this methos in you activity class and assign the instance of GoogleApiClient  like this

```
 GoogleApiClient  mPlusClient = buildGoogleApiClient();
```

please follow this [link](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-google-plus-login-example/) for complete process.

Comment: unfortunately, code by link dont work, after init in onCreate nothing happening(